# "..to hearing from you and getting inspired.."

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is the following sentence correct english?

*"We are looking forward to hearing from you and getting inspired by your photos"*

It might just be that english is my second language, but the *"getting"* in that sentence seem wrong to me. Should it rather be:

*"We are looking forward to hear from you and to get inspired by your photos"*?

This is for a tag line if that matters at all. I've seen questions regarding the "to hear" or "to hearing", but not together with a "getting".

Comment: "and being inspired" would probably flow better than "and getting inspired". But the tension comes from trying to have more than one verbal noun in the same sentence. Makes it feel strained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is good English.

The idiom *looking forward to* is properly complemented by either a noun or a gerund (an *-ing* form of a verb, functioning syntactically like a noun); it is not normally complemented by an infinitive, as in your proposed emendation. The *to* in *looking forward to* is a preposition, and is not the particle that forms a part of many an English infinitive, as in ***to*** be or not **to** be.

As to the particular gerund, *getting,* the verb *to get* is a [valid alternative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/get-passive) to *to be* in forming a passive.

Answer (score 2):

Well it comes down to the nature of inspiration. You would 'be inspired' or 'become inspired' not 'get inspired,' so '...being inspired by your photography.' would be the correct form.  To use the verb 'get' would be written '...getting inspiration from your photography.' which just sounds awkward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This put a whole lot of things in question (regarding our progressing web-project). So the header/slogan "Get inspired!" is also wrong per definition?

Comment: You can't really command someone to get inspired. I can say "I'm getting really inspired by this speech", but I can't tell the person next to me "you should get inspired too!" I know when I'm getting inspired by something, but I don't know how to get inspired.